# How can I create a list (file name, location) of activities (android classes) associated with each installed android app (on a user's phone)?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-intent, android-activity

I have so far programmed an application, which gets a list of all installed android applications (names and icons) on a user's phone;

But I would **also** like to create a list of all associated activities / android classes (on a user's phone) associated with each installed android application (*file name*, *location-al address*).

How can I go about accomplishing this?

Code so far:

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends ListActivity {
    private PackageManager packageManager = null;
    private List<ApplicationInfo> applist = null;
    private ApplicationAdapter listadaptor = null;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        packageManager = getPackageManager();

        new LoadApplications().execute();
    }

    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);

        return true;
    }

    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        return false;
    }


    @Override
    protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
        super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);

        ApplicationInfo app = applist.get(position);
        try {
            Intent intent = packageManager
                    .getLaunchIntentForPackage(app.packageName);

            if (null != intent) {
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, e.getMessage(),
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, e.getMessage(),
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }

    private List<ApplicationInfo> checkForLaunchIntent(List<ApplicationInfo> list) {
        ArrayList<ApplicationInfo> applist = new ArrayList<ApplicationInfo>();
        for (ApplicationInfo info : list) {
            try {
                if (null != packageManager.getLaunchIntentForPackage(info.packageName)) {
                    applist.add(info);
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        return applist;
    }

    private class LoadApplications extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
        private ProgressDialog progress = null;

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            applist = checkForLaunchIntent(packageManager.getInstalledApplications(PackageManager.GET_META_DATA));
            listadaptor = new ApplicationAdapter(MainActivity.this,
                    R.layout.snippet_list_row, applist);

            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onCancelled() {
            super.onCancelled();
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            setListAdapter(listadaptor);
            progress.dismiss();
            super.onPostExecute(result);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            progress = ProgressDialog.show(MainActivity.this, null,
                    "Loading application info...");
            super.onPreExecute();
        }

        @Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {
            super.onProgressUpdate(values);
        }
    }
```

**ApplicationAdapter.java**

```
public class ApplicationAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<ApplicationInfo> {
    private List<ApplicationInfo> appsList = null;
    private Context context;
    private PackageManager packageManager;

    public ApplicationAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId,
            List<ApplicationInfo> appsList) {
        super(context, textViewResourceId, appsList);
        this.context = context;
        this.appsList = appsList;
        packageManager = context.getPackageManager();
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return ((null != appsList) ? appsList.size() : 0);
    }

    @Override
    public ApplicationInfo getItem(int position) {
        return ((null != appsList) ? appsList.get(position) : null);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View view = convertView;
        if (null == view) {
            LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.snippet_list_row, null);
        }

        ApplicationInfo data = appsList.get(position);
        if (null != data) {
            TextView appName = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.app_name);
            TextView packageName = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.app_paackage);
            ImageView iconview = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.app_icon);
            appName.setText(data.loadLabel(packageManager));
            packageName.setText(data.packageName);
            iconview.setImageDrawable(data.loadIcon(packageManager));
        }
        return view;
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume that only if the activity of a third party application has its **android:exported** attribute set to true, will you be able to achieve what you are planning to. By default, all activities have android:exported set to false